# Close DevExtreme iOS App programmatically

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap, devextreme

I'm developing an iOS app with DevExtreme and I like to close it when the user tap on a specific menu item.
From [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T255917/how-do-i-close-application-programmitically) article and [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/OiuPQaJKeEI) it seems Apple doesn't allow to force closing apps. In fact the code snippet which comes preloaded in every DevExtreme project doesn't consider iOS platform.

```
function exitApp() {
    switch (DevExpress.devices.real().platform) {
        case "android":
            navigator.app.exitApp();
            break;
        case "win":
            MSApp.terminateApp('');
            break;

    }
}
```

My questions are:

- is force closing app a behavior which is not expected in iOS platform?
- if not, is there a sample I can use to implement the behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does indeed not allow apps that can kill themselves:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1561/_index.html